# Contact Form 7 - [your-name] - "Invalid mailbox syntax"

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

> Invalid mailbox syntax is used.

I have read the documentation and I'm still confused.

**Form**

```
<p>Your Name: (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Your Email: (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Your Phone:<br />
    [tel your-phone]</p>

<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

[honeypot phone_2]

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

**Mail**

```
In the following fields, you can use these mail-tags:  
[your-name] [your-email] [your-phone] [your-message]

**To:**  candyland@testing.com

**From:**  [your-name]  
  *!(configuration error) Invalid mailbox syntax is used.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that the mail address you provided in the "To" or "From" field (i.e. the destination address for the form) is incorrectly written or missing.

If you really only wrote `[your-name]` in the `From:` field, that's where the problem is: You need a valid email address in there, not just a name.

https://contactform7.com/configuration-errors/invalid-mailbox-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the mail address of the same domain name of your Wordpress website